# Login to ProxyServiceAdmin

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I try to login from Proxy Service to WSO 2 ESB administration service. My version of ESB is 4.6.0. I created following proxy service, but when I try to call getProxy operation I get System failure error.

Below is my proxy service:

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GenerateWebServiceFromXsd" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <enrich>
                <source type="inline" clone="true">
                   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://service.proxyadmin.carbon.wso2.org">                                                                                             
                      <soapenv:Header/>                                                                                             
                      <soapenv:Body>                                                                                                               

                   <aut:getProxy>

                   <aut:proxyName>Echo</aut:proxyName>   


                   </aut:getProxy>                                                                                                                           
                            </soapenv:Body>                                                                                                         
                         </soapenv:Envelope>
                      </source>
                      <target type="envelope"/>
                   </enrich>
                   <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('admin:admin'))" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                   <log level="full"/>
                </inSequence>
                <outSequence>
                   <send/>
                </outSequence>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="https://localhost:8243/services/ProxyServiceAdmin.ProxyServiceAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint"/>
                   <property name="HostnameVerifier" value="AllowAll" scope="axis2-client"/>
                </endpoint>
             </target>
             <description></description>
          </proxy>
```

And here is exception I get:

```
[2013-06-05 09:45:40,287] ERROR - Class System failure.null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.doAuthorization(AuthorizationHandler.java:112)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2013-06-05 09:45:40,288] ERROR - AxisEngine System failure.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System failure.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:101)
```

I can call AuthenticationAdmin.login without problem, ProxyService fails.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: How do you call proxy admin service?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's your use case?